# Do the latest D-Wave computers use Helium compounds for cooling?

Tags: experimental-realization, architecture, d-wave, superconducting-quantum-computing

Do the latest D-Wave machines use compounds of $\require{\mhchem}\ce{^{3}He}$ and $\ce{^{4}He}$ for cooling? If not, how does D-Wave approach cooling its plates low enough to achieve superconductivity? What compounds does DWave use for the plates in their fridge, and at what temperature do its plates reach superconductivity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they use $\require{\mhchem}\ce{^3He}$ and $\ce{^4He}$. No, they do not use compounds of these but instead a solution of these two (at the operating temperature) liquid nobel gases. The details can be found in the [wikipedia article on dilution refrigerators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_refrigerator).